# How to delete an object through his own class?

Tags: java, null, garbage

I know how to leave a signal for the Garbage Collector to delete an object by setting its reference variable to null:

```
Player player_reference = new Player();
player_reference = null; 
// Now the Garbage collector knows to release all the memory related to this object.
```

But how can I set the reference variable to null through the object's class?

```
class Player {
    public void doSomthing() {
        if(condition) {
            // some code which set the reference variable to null.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't unless the reference variable in question belongs to the class itself.

Comment: You can't and you don't need to. Every object is eligible for garbace collection once they are not referenced anymore

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken I believe that he is just asking how to delete player_reference by putting a function into the player class that is called delete that does the same thing as setting player_reference to null.

Comment: @Shelef I believe this is what you are looking for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089961/delete-this-object-inside-the-class?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know how to leave a signal for the Garbage Collector to delete an object by setting his reference variable to null

That's not really a "signal" - it's just making sure that the variable in question doesn't *prevent* garbage collectio. You really, really need to be clear about the differences between variables, references and objects. This question is meaningless:

> But how can i set the reference variable to null through the object class?

What reference? There could be multiple variables which all have values which are references to the same object. Or indeed there may be *no* such variables - you could be calling the method via some intermediate expression:

```
foo().bar().doSomething();
```

What variable you expect to be set to null in that case?

The object will be eligible for garbage collection when there's no way of getting to it any more in any thread. You don't need to manually delete it, or "signal" the garbage collector. It will just happen naturally.

Comment: I will explain what Im trying to do, mybe you will know how to help. i made a BlackTransition class that creates simple animation which turn the screen into black. the BlackTransition class make a Thread which handels the animation. the transition ends in about 3 sconds, so the object is no longer need. only the BlackTransition object knows when it ends. so after the transition ends i hoped to just delete the object through itself. of course I can invoke through the  BlackTransition to a method which set the reference to null. but there isnt other way?

Comment: @Shelef: You're over-thinking this by miles. Just let the garbage collector handle it - it will clean up the instance of `BlackTransition` when nothing refers to it any more. You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: the blacktransiton`s object holder class never knows when the blacktransition ends. I eventually made the BlackTransition Observerable.

Comment: @Shelef: Ah - if you've got something else holding onto `BlackTransition`, then that's a different matter.